# Não consigo trazer as classes relacionadas com EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Boa tarde pessoal, estou fazendo um exercício para fixar bem o EF usando sqlLite e net6 com c#,
mas não consigo de forma alguma trazer as classes relacionadas ao modelo.

```
namespace flashcards.Models
```

{
public class Stacks
{

```
    public Stacks(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id {get ; set ;}

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name {get ; set ;}

    public  IEnumerable<FlashCardDb> FlashCards { get; set; }
    

}
```

}

classe relacionada
namespace flashcards.Models
{
public class FlashCardDb
{

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get ; set ;}

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Expression { get ; set ;}

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string OppositeExpression{ get ; set ;}

   
    public  Stacks Stack { get ; set ;}

    [ForeignKey("StackId")]
    public int StackId { get ; set ;}

   
}
```

}

Olhando o relacionamento vemos que  Stacks tem N FlashCardDB e FlashCardDB  tem um Stack.
Esta última tem a propriedade StackID para manter o relacionamento.

O mapeamento de ambas segue:

```
    namespace flashcards.utils
{
    public class StackMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Stacks>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Stacks> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("STACKS");
            builder.HasKey(m=> m.Id);
            builder.HasIndex(m => m.Name);
            builder.Property(m => m.Name)
                   .IsRequired()
                   .HasMaxLength(50);
        }
    }
}

public class FlashCardDbMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<FlashCardDb>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FlashCardDb> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("FLASHCARDS");
            builder.HasKey(m=> m.Id);
            builder.HasIndex(m => m.Expression);
            builder.Property(m => m.Expression)
                   .IsRequired()
                   .HasMaxLength(50);

            builder.Property(m => m.OppositeExpression)
                    .HasMaxLength(50);                   

            
            builder.Property(m => m.StackId) 
                     .IsRequired();  

            builder.HasOne<Stacks>(m => m.Stack)                     
            
        }
    }
}
```

O Context está assim:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
```

{
public DbSet? Stacks { get; set; }
public DbSet? FlashCards { get; set; }

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=FlashCardDB.db;");
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Stacks>(new StackMap().Configure);
    modelBuilder.Entity<FlashCardDb>(new FlashCardDbMap().Configure);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Stacks>()
                    .HasMany(u => u.FlashCards);
   
    
     
    modelBuilder.Entity<FlashCardDb>()
                 .HasOne(b => b.Stack)
                 .WithMany(s => s.FlashCards)
                 .HasForeignKey(p => p.StackId);
                 ;

}
```

}

Tenho na base de dados um Stack de ID=1 e um FlashCardDB com id = 1 relacionado com StackId=1.

Ao executar o seguinte comando
" var sls = myContext.FlashCards.FirstOrDefault(m => m.StackId == 1);"

todos os campos são preenchidos corretamente, mas a property "Stack" vem como null.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado.

Detalhes

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.9"/>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="11.0.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="11.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.9"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: vc precisa dar o include... `myContext.FlashCards.Include(x=>x.Stack).FirstOr..`
outros pontos... o atributo ForeignKey, vc coloca na propriedade Stack apontando pra outra propriedade que é a FK

Comment: vc também pode habilitar o LazyLoading, e decalarar a propriedade Stack como virtual, assim quando ela for solicitada, o select é feito no banco

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela ajuda. Mas não acho o método include no FlashCards(Dbset)

Comment: Interessante que dentro do fonte mycontext eu consigo acessar o método Include, mas fora ele não fica disponível.

Comment: vai ter que adicionar o using do `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: Agora deu certo. Obrigado.